# Dynamically comparing records in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I've got about 15 tables I need to check for records that don't match, based on an ID.  So, for example, I've got one table with contact info:

```
TransID FirstName   LastName    Phone           Extn
80071   Michael     Kriegel     888-555-6265    1111
80071   Pam         Morrow      888-555-9999    2222
80071   Barbara     Smith       888-555-7770    3333
80071   Yessika     Zurita      888-555-6622    4444
80072   Pam         Morrow      888-555-9999    2222
80072   Barbara     Smith       888-555-7777    3333
80072   Yessika     Zurita      888-555-9954    4444
80072   Michael     Kriegel     888-555-6265    1122
```

We've got Michael Kriegel whose Extn is different between the two TransIDs, and we have Barbara Smith and Zurita Yesskia whose phone numbers are different.

What I need to do is figure out a way to show which records are different, and show which field(s) is/are different.  But I also need to write this so it's generic, because I don't want to hard-code 15 different comparisons.

I'd like to get my output to look like this:

```
Name                  Field         TransID_80071   TransID_80072
Michael Kriegel       Extn          1111            1122
Barbara Smith         Phone         888-555-7770    888-555-7777
Zurita Yessika        Phone         888-555-6622    888-555-9954
```

I'm messing around with UNPIVOTs, but I can't get there.  I've got this code:

```
SELECT TransID , Value , FieldName
FROM 
   (SELECT Max(TransID) as TransID, Convert(VarChar(250),FirstName) as FirstName, 
       Convert(VarChar(250),LastName) as LastName, 
       Convert(VarChar(250),Phone) as Phone, Convert(VarChar(250),CoExtn) as CoExtn
   FROM tblSQLContacts
   WHERE TransID IN ('80071', '80072')
   GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Phone, CoExtn 
   HAVING count(*) < 2   
   ) p
UNPIVOT
   (FieldName  FOR Value IN 
      (FirstName, LastName, Phone, CoExtn)
)AS unpvt
```

This gives me a result of:

```
TransID Value         FieldName
80071   FirstName     Barbara
80071   LastName      Smith
80071   Phone         888-555-7770
80071   Extn          3333
80072   FirstName     Barbara
80072   LastName      Smith
80072   Phone         888-555-7777
80072   Extn          3333
80071   FirstName     Michael
80071   LastName      Kriegel
80071   Phone         888-555-6265
80071   Extn          1111
80072   FirstName     Michael
80072   LastName      Kriegel
80072   Phone         888-555-6265
80072   Extn          1122
80071   FirstName     Yessika
80071   LastName      Zurita
80071   Phone         888-555-6622
80071   Extn          4444
80072   FirstName     Yessika
80072   LastName      Zurita
80072   Phone         888-555-9954
80072   Extn          4444
```

So, I'm pulling the right records, but I can't figure out how to get it into the format I want it in.  Can anyone get me over the finish line?

Comment: can first_name and last_name change too?

Comment: That's part of the problem.  **Any** field can change.  Although, theoretically, if either First Name or Last Name changed I can't realistically compare them.  So for argument's sake let's say they'll never change.  But keep in mind there are probably about 40 or so fields per table, what I posted above is just a snippet of data.

Comment: You are only interested in these two TransIDs?

Comment: No, the user will actually select the two TransIDs to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have data like this..

```
CREATE TABLE #tSQLContacts
    ([TransID] int, [FirstName] varchar(250), [LastName] varchar(250), [Phone] varchar(250), [Extn] varchar(250))
;

INSERT INTO #tSQLContacts
    ([TransID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Phone], [Extn])
VALUES
    (80071, 'Michael', 'Kriegel', '888-555-6265', '1111'),
    (80071, 'Pam', 'Morrow', '888-555-9999', '2222'),
    (80071, 'Barbara', 'Smith', '888-555-7770', '3333'),
    (80071, 'Yessika', 'Zurita', '888-555-6622', '4444'),
    (80072, 'Pam', 'Morrow', '888-555-9999', '2222'),
    (80072, 'Barbara', 'Smith', '888-555-7777', '3333'),
    (80072, 'Yessika', 'Zurita', '888-555-9954', '4444'),
    (80072, 'Michael', 'Kriegel', '888-555-6265', '1122')
;
```

you can get your desired result like this.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk1, ColumnName ORDER BY ColumnValue) Rnk2  
    FROM (
        SELECT  *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName], [LastName]) Rnk1
        FROM    #tSQLContacts
        WHERE   TransID IN ('80071', '80072')
    ) t
    UNPIVOT
    (
        ColumnValue
        FOR ColumnName IN ([Phone], [Extn] )
    ) up
)
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ',LastName) AS NAME,
            ColumnName AS Field,
            [80071] AS [TransID_80071],
            [80072] AS [TransID_80072]
FROM (
    SELECT  FirstName,
            LastName,
            ColumnName,
            ColumnValue,
            TransID
    FROM    cte t1
    WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   cte t2
                     WHERE  t1.Rnk1 = t2.Rnk1
                            AND t1.ColumnName = t2.ColumnName
                            AND t2.Rnk2 > 1 )
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ColumnValue) 
    FOR TransID IN ([80071], [80072])
) p
```

this could most likely be done dynamically, but I'm not sure we have enough information to do that for you.

Comment: Holy Christmas Trees!  I've got a lot of customizing to do to make it work with my actual data, but this gives me exactly what I asked for.  One question, though; the UNPIVOT portion seems to require the exact field names to be input.  If I'm running this on a table with 40 fields, and I don't know which (if any) fields contain different data, would I just put every field name in there?  Or is it every field name **except** FirstName, LastName and TransID?

Comment: The way I do it now, I query sys.columns to build a string with all the field names dynamically.

Comment: every field except those 3..  you need to determine which fields are the identifier and not include those fields.

Comment: One last question.  If I wanted this output to end up in a Global Temp table named ##Temp20, where would I put the "Into ##Temp20" statement?  After the very first SELECT?  After the SELECT CONCAT?

Comment: After `Select CONCAT` before `FROM (`